# Alignment issue of the SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, slidingdrawer

I have created a SlidingDrawer which content the list view i want to align the handle of the SlidingDrawer at the right corner of the screen but it always align at the center ...please suggest me how to solve this problem...

```
     <SlidingDrawer
    android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:handle="@+id/drawerHandle"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drawerHandle"
        android:text="list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work

```
    <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/drawerHandle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent
        android:gravity="right"
    >
      <Button        
         android:text="list"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content">
      </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Sam ..thnks for the response...i tried this ..but when i dont tap on the button but on the another part of screen at bottom, that also open the SlidingDrawer..i want to open only when the user tap on the button.....

Comment: try **android:background="@android:color/transparent"**. technically if the panel is transparent it should not receive any touch/click events.